# show image gallery on modal popup

Tags: javascript, modalpopup

i have a dropdownlist containing some items,,,on selecteditem index i have displayed modal popup,,,this modal popup is used to show image gallery,,i have seen some posts where datalist is used to show images but they dont seem to work efficiently,plz provide some posts which  show image gallery and enlarge them as well....

Answer (score 1):

[Lightbox](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/) is a simple, unobtrusive script used to overlay images on the current page. It's a snap to setup and works on all modern browsers.

Also take a look at this link

[15 Amazing jQuery Image Gallery/Slideshow Plugins and Tutorials](http://speckyboy.com/2009/06/03/15-amazing-jquery-image-galleryslideshow-plugins-and-tutorials/)

Comment: looks good bt tell me is it possible to insert radio buttons in the gallery so that user cud select any image